# How do I reinstall the HTTPD?

Tags: linux, centos, reinstall, httpd

I have a problem with my server CentOs7. I installed httpd, it works fine, but I reinstalled for some reason, but after that it never works and throws error. Is there any way I can remove all httpd files?

I tried removing `/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service`
and `/usr/sbin/httpd`
and `/etc/httpd`,
but then when I removed httpd and httpd-tools it throws error again:

> Job for httpd.service failed. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

systemctl status httpd.service:

```linux
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Tue 2021-02-23 04:13:01 EST; 21s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 5396 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 5396 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 23 04:13:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Feb 23 04:13:01 localhost.localdomain httpd[5396]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
Feb 23 04:13:01 localhost.localdomain httpd[5396]: httpd (pid 3043) already running
Feb 23 04:13:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Feb 23 04:13:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Feb 23 04:13:01 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you manually removing the service files instead of simply launching `yum remove httpd`?

Have you tried at all to remove the service via yum and then reinstall it again with `yum install httpd`? What's the output?

The error reports that the service is already running: `httpd (pid 3043) already running`

What's the result of `ps -aux | less`?